# Can I say “raise oneself to be king” or “raise oneself a king”?

Tags: expressions

The question is just the title.

I don't know which following expression is correct:

> 1. raise oneself to be king
> 2. raise oneself to be a king
> 3. raise oneself a king

And I wonder if there are some better versions to express the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

We would not say any of these to mean that he became king by his own efforts. *Raise X to be Y* means to nurture and educate X with the goal of X becoming Y. Most often parents are said to raise their children to be doctors or lawyers or observant Christians or pillars of the community; but a horse-breeder may also raise a colt to be a racehorse or plowhorse or riding horse.

If you want to use *raise* I suggest using a preposition phrase:

> He raised himself to {the kingship/the throne/the crown}.

Comment: What about an animal, say a monkey or an ape? Raise itself...?

Comment: @dennylv raise itself where?

Comment: I mean, what if I want to say, a monkey or an ape raised itself to be a monkey king or an ape king?

Comment: @dennylv Supposing other primates had comparable vocations and institutions, the idiom would have the same meaning.